Postgres: Increment date by one day on every insert
I want to create a daily random fact table, that will store a list of facts everyday.
I have a table like this
create table random_facts
(
    id           serial primary key,
    fact         text      not null,
    display_date date      not null unique default now()
);

I want to auto-increment display_date by one day on every insert.
For example after inserting facts like this
Insert into random_facts (fact)values (unnest(ARRAY ['The shortest war in history lasted 38 minutes', 'Russell Crowe plays Maximus in the movie Gladiator', 'Australia is wider than the moon.']));

the data should look like this



fact
display_date




The shortest war in history lasted 38 minutes
2024-04-26


Russell Crowe plays Maximus in the movie Gladiator
2024-04-27


Australia is wider than the moon.
2024-04-28



How can I increment display_date of one day everytime one row is inserted based on the last row inserted?
I am using Postgres 14.5

Because of concurrency, this is going to be hard. Unless you lock the table when inserting a new record. Select the max(date) for your current data and use this for your new record. And release the lock for the next insert. This is slow by design, but the only way it can work.

I see. My original idea was to select the last row inserted and add + 1 day to it but could not figure out how to do it.

Its easy, you can create a sequence for your initial date in seconds using the Unix epoch (the number of seconds since January 1, 1970). For example we create a sequence starting today
create sequence date_next_day_seq
start with 1714175999 /*value in seconds for today*/ 
increment 86400; /*increment of one day 24*60*60 */

and then change your table definition to
create table random_facts
(
    id           serial primary key,
    fact         text      not null,
    display_date date      not null unique 
    default to_timestamp(nextval('date_next_day_seq'::regclass)::double precision)::date
);

and on your insert operation you will get



id
fact
display_date




1
The shortest war in history lasted 38 minutes
2024-04-26


2
Russell Crowe plays Maximus in the movie Gladiator
2024-04-27


3
Australia is wider than the moon.
2024-04-28




Easy for you maybe, Thank you very much!

Although i have to point out that is not a perfect solution, because values in a sequence could be lost, specially using your insert instruction with unnest function (don't know why) so better use a conventional insert  Insert into random_facts (fact) values ('The shortest war in history lasted 38 minutes'), ('Russell Crowe plays Maximus in the movie Gladiator'), ('Australia is wider than the moon.');

I usually use something along these lines: insert into random_facts (fact) values unnest($1) in code. That is why I used unnest but there might be a better way. I didn't know about the caveats of unnest.
In this particular case, the values will be hardcoded in a migration script.
